# Animation: render stops before animation is done

Tags: rendering, animation

I had a simple animation (student project) which was working fine.  I decided I would slow it down a bit, as follows:  in Dope Sheet, select all, Scale, then drag the whole shebang R to start on Frame 0 as before.  Used to be 170 frames long, now 270.  Preview is fine.  All seemed well.

Then I rendered it.  The rendered version stops (black screen) after frame 170, "remembering" the old length.  Yes, I did remember to set Begin and End frames in the Animation parameters :-)  They are set to 1 and 270.  If I step through in Preview, rendering individual frames, I can see that frame 170 is normal and frame 171 is black-screen as are all subsequent.

There must be some other place -- other than the Timeline and the Animation panel -- where length of animation is set, but I can't find it.  Can anyone clue me in?

Comment: Maybe delete everything (objects, materials, scripts, images) in the file, then try again. If it still renders incorrectly upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In the project's folder you might find another folder(s) there called "Blend_cache" or similar.   Try deleting those.  Also in Blende's "Temp" folder delete everything in there when the former doesn't work.    If you should find you can no longer output video it will be because Blender's forgotten where the temp folder is!  The solution is to save your work (twice using differerent filenames - (append "BU" to original name)  Exit Blender altogether, then click on the project Blender file again to start it up.  It should find it's temp folder this time.

Comment: I tried the "delete everything" route.  The problem remained stubbornly present even after I had got rid of all objects in all layers.  It did not go away until I got into the VSE and... oh yes, there was a Scene Strip in there because I had been fooling about with some audio clips for a sound track.  So... Revert the file, put everything back the way it was, and just delete the Scene Strip -- and that seems to fix the problem.  It appears that there are 3 places that must agree on the length of the clip:  the Render parameters pane, the TimeLine pane, and the VSE master Scene Strip... yes?